# What is the reason of error for delpoyment in Visual Studio?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2015

After compiling sample code, payout.sol in Visual Studio, I just tried to deploy it. I got the following error message:

> Deployment to http://localhost:8000/ started! User used for deployment: testuser User check failed.

What is the reason for this error?

Comment: Show the code then if you want help.